# Fix static ip address problems in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, static-ip

I used Network Manager in Ubuntu 10.04 to set a static ip address and assigned one that was already in use. Now my computer will not boot (nfs crashes).

I booted from a live cd to change the configuration on the file system in /etc/network/interfaces but the file looks to be the default. Where does the network manager (the gui from system-> preferences) store it's configuration so I can overwrite it and enter the correct ip addresss and have a happy working computer again.

thanks!!

Comment: Were you looking at the file system on your hard drive or on the LiveCD (aka did you mount your hard drive and look there)?

Comment: the files system on the hard drive - i checked the etc/fstab file to make sure it was the right files system and it has all of the nfs mounts defined. the etc/network/interfaces file looks unmodified even though i changed the setting in network manager via the gui.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you were looking at the `/etc/network/interfaces` file on the LiveCD, rather than the file that exists on the hard drive.

Mount your hard drive using the `mount` command, like this:

```
mount -t [fs type] [/dev/device] [mountpoint]
```

Make sure you replace the parts in [ and ] brackets with real values. Also remember that the mountpoint needs to exist before it will mount.

After it is mounted you should be able to access the files on the hard-drive itself, and from there modify the `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

Comment: the correct drive was mounted in /media automatically so I'm sure I was editing the correct etc/network/interfaces file. is there anywhere else network manager would have stored the info I entered in the gui? If I just edit and add the correct values to interfaces file will it override whatever was set in the gui? thanks for your reply!

Comment: If you directly modify /etc/network/interfaces it will override any previous changes. Again, make sure you're in /media/HDD#/etc/network/interfaces where HDD# is the identifier for the partition with the filesystem on it, and not simply /etc/network/interfaces which will only modify the file the LiveCD has stored in RAM.

Answer (score 1):

You can allways remove the ethernet cable (or disable wi-fi) and boot, modify the setttings and plug in ethernet cable again.